# Air vent on the wall big gap

Tags: repair

[image]

Hi I have a huge gap between my air vent and to my wall and I can’t screw jt into the wall because there is brick there. Is there a way I can seal it and paint it... thanks

Comment: I take it this is an outside wall you're talking about here?  Can you gain access to the ductwork from below?

Comment: Haven’t looked at it and the vent is inside the kitchen and the outside wall is behind it

Answer (score 2):

Get a 1x2 or just some molding from your home store and make a frame and attach it to the wall. Then slide the vent up against it and caulk it a paintable caulk. Then paint it to match the wall or the trim, whatever floats your boat. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I’ll give it a try